# replace all image url in my post

Tags: regex

I have deleted all `<a href=""></a>` tags in my blog with this regex expression: 
`<a\s[^>]*>  $1` and now I need to change all my image URLs from:

```
<img src="http://files.tampo.ua/files/news/part_38/388705/1.jpg" width="500" height="291" border="0" class="c24" />
```

to:

```
<img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/85819604/1.jpg" width="500" height="291" border="0" class="c24" />
```

So I need to replace the main path to the image server.

http://clip2net.com/s/22PwP

Comment: Is every old image found in the `http://files.tampo.ua/files/news/part_38/388705/` folder, and will every new image be found in the `https://dl.dropbox.com/u/85819604/` folder?

Comment: Every old image found in the http://files.tampo.ua/files/news/ and part_38 can be change, but all new images placed in https://dl.dropbox.com/u/85819604/ folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `http://files.tampo.ua/files/news/[^/]*/[^/]*/` with `https://dl.dropbox.com/u/85819604/`

Comment: Thanks Matt! I have something change in this code to this http://files.tampo.ua/files/news/[^/]*/[^/]*/ because it was one unnecessary folder 388705/ in my new image url. Thanks very much for helping!!!

Comment: Right, left out that one last folder in the regex. I updated the answer above.

Comment: all this path can be changed part_38/388705/

Comment: oh, gotcha, updated the answer again. It should match your first comment now. Cheers!

Comment: I'm sorry it's my fault, have write a little bit wrong. Thanks again!